# Duhamel's Principle Confusion

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

I am trying to figure out how to apply [Duhamel's Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duhamel%27s_principle) to solve differential equations.

I have been able to solve linear $1$st order ODEs, i.e, $y' = \frac{2}{3} y + 3,\ y(0) = 0$, which has the solution $y(t) = \frac{9e^\frac{2t}{3} - 9}{2}$.  First I solve a new ODE with the forcing function and initial condition swapped, $w' = \frac{2}{3} w,\ w(0) = 3$, which has the solution $w(s) = 3e^{\frac{2s}{3}}$.  Then I integrate the solution; $\int_0^t 3e^{\frac{2s}{3}}\ ds$ produces $\frac{9e^\frac{2t}{3} - 9}{2}$ as expected.

Extending this approach to linear ODEs of higher order, my experiments so far seem to conclude that swapping the forcing function with the initial condition of the highest derivative works.  Thus $y'' - 2y' + y = 5,\ y(0) = 0,\ y'(0) = 0$ becomes $w'' - 2w' + w = 0,\ w(0) = 0,\ w'(0) = 5$, and $y''' - 2y'' - y' + 2y = \pi,\ y(0) = 0,\ y'(0) = 0,\ y''(0) = 0$ becomes $w''' - 2w'' - w' + 2w = 0,\ w(0) = 0,\ w'(0) = 0, w''(0) = \pi$, which each produce the correct answer to their original ODE after being integrated from $0$ to $t$.

Pretty much anything else I do seems to break the algorithm and provide the wrong answer, including if

- I swap the forcing function to any initial condition except that of
  the highest derivative
- The inputs or outputs of any of the initial
  conditions are originally nonzero, including lower-derivative initial
  conditions not involved in the swap
- I have boundary conditions
  instead of initial conditions
- The forcing function depends on the independent variable, since it could then not be sensibly swapped to the output of an initial condition

I cannot seem to extend this approach to PDEs at all, even though PDEs are what the technique was designed for.  I tried to solve $u_x + 3u_t = 5x,\ u(x,\ 0) = 0$, which has the solution $u = \frac{30xt - 5t^2}{18}$.  Solving $w_x + 3w_s = 0,\ w(x,\ 0) = 5x$ yields $w = \frac{15x - 5s}{3}$, and $\int_0^t \frac{15x - 5s}{3}\ ds = \frac{30xt - 5t^2}{6}$, off from the correct answer by a factor of $3$.

How am I applying this principle incorrectly in the PDE case, and are the restrictive apparent limits described above to its application to ODEs really insuperable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in your PDE comes from your rather unusual notation of the transport equation:
$$u_x + 3u_\color{red}t = 5x \textbf{, but it's more common to write: } u_\color{red}t+ a u_\color{blue}x = \phi(x).$$
This means that your homogeneous equation is now:
$$w_s + \frac{1}{3}w_x = \frac 53 x\implies w(x,s) = \dfrac{15x-5s}{9}$$
and now you should be good.

For your questions about ODE's, it's literally mentioned in the wikipedia link you provided that you should put the inhomogeneous term to the highest order derivative term in the initial conditions as:
$$P(\partial _{t})G=0,\;\partial _{t}^{j}G(0)=0,\quad 0\leq j\leq m-2,\;\partial _{t}^{m-1}G(0)=1/a_{m}.$$